# What's wrong with my flashvars code?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flashvars

I'm trying to read flashvars into my flash file by modifying the standard HTML published out of Flash CS5.  The following isn't working:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <title>flashVarsTests</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="flashContent"> 
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="flashVarsTests" align="middle"> 
                <param name="movie" value="flashVarsTests.swf" /> 
                <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 
                <param name="play" value="true" /> 
                <param name="loop" value="true" /> 
                <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
                <param name="scale" value="showall" /> 
                <param name="menu" value="true" /> 
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" /> 
                <param name="salign" value="" /> 
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
                <param name="flashvars" value="message1=HelloWorld&message2=HeyGuy" /> 
                <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashVarsTests.swf" width="550" height="400"> 
                    <param name="movie" value="flashVarsTests.swf" /> 
                    <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 
                    <param name="play" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="loop" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" /> 
                    <param name="menu" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" /> 
                    <param name="salign" value="" /> 
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
                    <param name="flashvars" value="message1=HelloWorld&message2=HeyGuy" /> 
                <!--<![endif]--> 
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /> 
                    </a> 
                <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                </object> 
                <!--<![endif]--> 
            </object> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

ActionScript:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);

function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
  var flashVars=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
  var msg1:String=flashVars.message1;
  var msg2:String=flashVars.message2;
  text1.text=msg1;
  text2.text=msg2;
}
```

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the TLF TEXT control, when you add it to the stage the flashvars begins not working .
just don't use it and your flashvars will work fine .
i've faced the same problem and i got it solved by not using TLF TEXT control.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once! Nothing worked until I reverted the text control to classic from TLF. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

var flashVars= LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

Here is a lengthy tutorial on how to do this:
http://blog.six4rty.ch/tutorials/flash-flashvars-in-as3/